# How can you get the actual value of the string a Javascript regex matches?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to write a Javascript function that will take a string with `<0>` (where 0 can really be any number) in it and remove it and get the actual value of the number in it. For example, if it is given this sentence:

```
'By now you\'re probably familiar with <0>X, a drawing application that has won an <1>Awards and plenty of attention for its user interface, which has rethought the way basic interactions like <2>pinch-to-zoom or <3>color selection should work on a touchscreen.'
```

I want it to give me back this String:

```
'By now you\'re probably familiar with X, a drawing application that has won an Awards and plenty of attention for its user interface, which has rethought the way basic interactions like pinch-to-zoom or color selection should work on a touchscreen.'
```

and this array:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Currently I have this:

```
function(sentence) {
  return sentence.split(/\<[0-9]+\>/).join('');
}
```

which obviously just returns the sentence. I need to have the number values inside the tags. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does it need to correct the spelling of Awards magically too?

Comment: You want it to strip out the `<0>` characters, and return an array *and* the sentence with those numbers stripped?

Comment: You can probably do something like this with a [`replace` callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), but `replace` will only ever *return* a string. You could use an outer-scope variable to collect the array values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function regexAndArray (str) {
    var reg = /(<(\d+)>)/g,
        results = {
            string : '',
            stripped : []
        };
    results.string = str.replace(reg, function(a,b,c){
        results.stripped.push(c);
        return '';
    });
    return results;
}

console.log(regexAndArray('By now you\'re probably familiar with <0>X, a drawing application that has won an <1>Awards and plenty of attention for its user interface, which has rethought the way basic interactions like <2>pinch-to-zoom or <3>color selection should work on a touchscreen.'));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Db8hZ/).

References:

- [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).